# Are Interceptors & Decorators part of CDI?

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7

Many books list them under CDI (Context and Dependency Injection) but in the Java EE 7 API there are listed under different packages from the CDI

- javax.decorator
- javax.interceptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See JSR-346 for the answer. You can find it [here](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=346)

Decorators are part of the CDI specification. You can find it in chapter 8.

Interceptors are not part of the CDI specification. It is referenced in 1.2.5 as a relationship to the CDI specification. It is part of the EJB specification JSR-345, see chapter 7 in that specification.

Comment: The statement about interceptors is not entirely correct. In fact, there are 2 types of interceptors: interceptors were defined for EJBs 3.0 in Java EE 5, even before CDI was available, and with CDI in Java EE 6, there is new type of interceptor, which is more general. CDI interceptors can be applied to any CDI bean, not only EJB, and obsolete older EJB 3.0 interceptors. The newer CDI interceptors are of course part of CDI specification, right below the decorators in chapter 9.

Comment: OK, I was not entirely correct either. The interceptors mentioned in EJB specification and CDI specification are the same, They both use `@javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke` annotation to mark interceptor methods. However, the 2 specifications differ in the way how interceptors are applied to components. In EJB specification, you apply interceptors using `@Interceptors` on EJB. In CDI, you apply interceptors on any CDI bean using `@InterceptorBinding` and you must turn them on in beans.xml.